# Why does SELECT FOR UPDATE not support aggregations (among others)?

Tags: postgresql

I checked the PostgreSQL docs for https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html and wondered why there are so many exceptions where FOR UPDATE is not supported, like

1. GROUP BY
2. HAVING
3. WINDOW
4. DISTINCT
5. UNION
6. INTERSECT
7. EXCEPT

Is there a compelling logical reason for that, or is it just not yet implemented?

Comment: [Why can't I use SELECT ... FOR UPDATE with aggregate functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455473/why-cant-i-use-select-for-update-with-aggregate-functions#:~:text=The%20syntax%20select%20.%20.%20.%20for,just%20a%20temporary%20result%20set.) , it might apply to PostgreSQL as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by `WINDOW`, but the others are clear to me: once you have executed these SQL constructs, the rows in the result set don't correspond to individual table rows any more, so it is not clear which rows should be locked.

For example, if you query

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM tab
GROUP BY name
HAVING name = 'laurenz'
FOR UPDATE;
```

PostgreSQL will select all rows, sort them by `name` (explicitly or with a hash table), count the values for each group and construct result rows consisting of the count. By the time that aggregation is done, the result rows cannot be linked back to the original table rows any more. This is quite obvious since I did not include `name` in the `SELECT` list, but it makes no real difference.

It could theoretically be possible to change that, but there is not much point in doing so.

Comment: Well, maybe the DB could lock the rows (internally) before aggregating them and returning the result-set. But yes, your explanation makes sense.

Comment: You have to lock the rows in the end. If you lock them before grouping, and there is a `HAVING` clause that discards the rows, they certainly shouldn't be locked.